# JPA fetch on 3 levels

Tags: java, jpa, fetch

I need to do something like that :

The structure is :

X contains a list of Y. 
Y contains or not a list of Z.

```
Xroot.fetch("Y", JoinType.INNER);
Xroot.fetch("Y.Z", JoinType.LEFT);
```

But in JPA the last line does not work. Any ideas how to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fetch inside the child.

```
Fetch<X,Y> yFetch = xRoot.fetch("Y", JoinType.INNER); 
yFetch.fetch("Z", JoinType.LEFT);
```

Of course, you can type it fluidly as well

```
xRoot.fetch("Y", JoinType.INNER).fetch("Z", JoinType.LEFT);
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Fetch.html.

Answer (score 1):

Because JPA 2.0 specification does not require support for multiple level fetch, there is no vendor independent solution:

> Multiple levels of fetch joins are not required to be supported by an
>   implementation of this specification. Applications that use
>   multi-level fetch joins will not be portable.

According [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins) Hibernate supports multiple level fetch at least in HQL queries. With EclipseLink [eclipselink.left-join-fetch](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/q_left-join-fetch.htm#CHDEFDDC) query hint can be used.